# saml integration with nodejs and express framework issue

Tags: angular, angularjs, express, authentication, saml-2.0

Im facing saml integration with nodejs and express framework and followed the below link

[Saml Integration URL](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1248145/How-to-use-SAML-in-an-Angular-JS-Single-Page-Appli)

I have created the IDP Metadata with [IDP Site](https://auth0.com/)  and there allowed callback was [Callback URL](http://localhost:8080/sso/acs)

And later with client_id and x.509 cert, i have created the SP Metadata with [SP Metadata Generation](https://www.samltool.com/online_tools.php) and there also i have mentioned the callback url.

For me login page is opening and when i click on submit post given the credentials the site is keep on loading and in browser devtools the callback url is in pending state.

[devtools network response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIQdM.png)

I have stopped firewall and there is no other proxy configurations

And im using latest samlify 2.8.10

Please help me out on this to get it resolve

Thanks in advance